# How can I check to match all characters on the line to a variable? Python

Tags: python

This is my current code:

```
counter = 0
x = input()
if x == 'DONE':
  break
with open('text.txt') as f:
  datafile = f.readlines()
  found = False
for line in datafile:
   if x in line:
```

My goal is to check if the input is in the file. My issue is that the program can take any character and match it to multiple lines in the file. How can I make the program check if the input is a full line in the file? For example if I typed in "s" it wouldn't match it to every character named "s" in the file, instead it would see that there is no line named "s" and will not add to the counter. Instead when I type something like "serbia", and there is a line named "serbia".
I am somewhat new to this platform and if my post is not very clear or up to standard please inform me.

Comment: You seem to know how to make an exact comparison of strings, based on the `if x == 'DONE':` line.

Comment: Is there a way I can go through every line and check each one using this?

Comment: You already have that in your code as well - 
`for line in datafile:`

Comment: To compare entire line try: `if x == line.rstrip():` rather than `if x in line:`.  This way you're comparing the entire line except for the trailing newline character at the end.

Comment: This method works, thanks.